# JavaScript Input Type date | does not work on Android Device 4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

My input type is like below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Students DOB"  class="inputText" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  >
```

In the output on the Android devices, the Calendar does not work on Android device 4.1.2 (Jellybean), but the Calendar works on Android device 4.2 (kitkat)..

Comment: **Why** is your input type like that? Are you aware it (changing the `type`) doesn't work on at least some versions of IE?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if give a direct input type as date, it still does not work on this device. I have the place holder to get a Hint for the user.. can you suggest where i need to correct my code ?

Comment: I wouldn't play games with `type`. Either use `date` or use `text`. If you feel the need to play games with `type`, do it by having two inputs and showing/hiding the relevant one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, this time i used the code if ( $('#test')[0].type != 'date' ) $('#test').datepicker(); and still the calendar does not show up in the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use drop downs for the date instead of going for the default date picker as it is a hybrid app you may face issues with the versions and platforms , and even the default date picker in windows won't work fine all the time

Comment: I was thinking, how will the DB accept the value of different dropdowns as date-time format to save in dB..what i need to do is, capture all vaues of the each dropdowns, save them in a format accepted by DB and then put it in DB

Comment: Frankly yes you should just accept it as a string and change it into date format with the best optimised format it will be 2 or 3 lines of code you can use something like this:

var cmpDate = dob_month + "/" + .dob_date + "/"+ dob_year;
var dob = new Date(cmpDate);

something like this