# Date field does not appear properly In react

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs

I have one input field whose type is date and placeholder is "Enter your date". But what happened was placeholder does not show up in the mobile app. (we are building the mobile app using html, css, bootstrap and react.js and porting via cordova"). So I am following this link, to get the label appeared and when clicked `date pop` should appear. But this seems to be not working, when inspected the element in chrome, onfocus and onblur seem to be disappearing. Is there anyway to make it work in react.

```
<ElementsBasket name='nextActionDate' 
                      data={this.props.newLead.get('actions').get('nextActionDate')}>
    <div className="form-group">

       <input type="text" className="form-control" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='date')"
                       placeholder="Type your date here.." 
                       value={this.props.newLead.get('actions').get('nextActionDate')}
                       onChange={onFieldChanged.bind(this, 'actions.nextActionDate')}
                       />       
     </div>
</ElementsBasket>
```

ps: I am following this link 
[Not showing placeholder for input type="date" field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-place-holder-for-input-type-date-field-ios-phonegap-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React your events should be called `onFocus` and `onBlur` (note capitalisation)

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

edit:

The other issue is that you are setting the handlers to a string - `onFocus="(this.type='date')"` and they should be a function. So set them like you set your onChange event -

```
 <input type="text" onFocus = {this._onFocus} onBlur={this._onBlur}
```

Now `this` refers to the object that contains your render function so you need to implement the appropriate function in that object.
eg.

```
_onFocus: function(e){
    e.currentTarget.type = "date";
},
_onBlur: function(e){
    e.currentTarget.type = "text";
    e.currentTarget.placeholder = "Enter a Date";
},
```

Comment: Still the problem persists man, I did the capitalisation. They are not (onFocus and onBlur) getting loaded!

Comment: Works fine, except there is one problem. I need to click the date field two times. First time the type="text" and placeholder is "Next Action Date". When I used onFocus type="date". So If i click at Next Action Date, onFocus is getting fired, and again a white button field appears which does not anything. The whole problem is with this empty button. I don't want this button. So when I click this button Calendar will appear. Is there anyway that I could just click the placeholder Next Action Date and make the calendar appear? I tried onClick too. But no result, it is also taking two steps

Comment: I dont think so (take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975667/html-input-type-date-open-calendar-by-default ) . This is kind of a different issue now and possibly will vary depending on browser (Android version). To be honest I dont think writing code to switch input type like this is a great idea and could cause problems. I was just answering your question about why onfocus and onblur was not working in React

Comment: Yea even I felt the same, but having a button with no text on it did not seem nice.

Comment: This doesn't work on Safari for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

this is simpler

```
<input
   type="text"
   onFocus={
    (e)=> {
      e.currentTarget.type = "date";
      e.currentTarget.focus();
     }
   }
   placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
/>
```

Comment: This one worked just fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the ***date*** type appears with default placeholder i.e. **mm/dd/yyyy**, that's why our ***placeholder*** *attribute* is not displayed as it is in ***text*** type.

So we can use event handlers `onFocus` and `onBlur` to make it work.
We can add these handlers in *arrow function* structure like this -

```
<input
  type="text"
  onFocus={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "date")}
  onBlur={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "text")}
  placeholder="No date found"
/>
```

[output will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls3Gh.png)

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      onFocus={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "date")}
      onBlur={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "text")}
      placeholder="No date found"
    />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Hope it helps you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't bring in the place holder when the input type is Date , one way to solve this issue is dynamically changing the input type `on-focus` , but that is not a good practice , my suggestion is not to go with the default date pickers instead you can use the drop downs

You can also refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995176/javascript-input-type-date-does-not-work-on-android-device-4-2/30996681#30996681) .Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Please check the link in ps of my question

Comment: Ok checked  but it seems that he also trying to say that you should change the type ! and your onfocus and onblur is doing the same thing , if you are using his logic then you should change the type to text onblur

Comment: Even then the problem is not fixed. onfocus and onblur are not even loading in react

Comment: Can you please try to replace onchange with onKeydown

Comment: Dude, my problem is that onfocus and onblur are not even loading, in my case onfocus would make the type=date, so this is not getting fired

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  onFocus={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "date")}
  onBlur={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "text")}
  placeholder="plz select your date"
/>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, consider including a short explanation above your code